# Yes No check_box_tag in Rails not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am going crazy handling checkboxes in rails.

I have Yes,No **check_box_tag** in rails which are not working correctly becuase data is not being persisted correctly.

e.g when I uncheck a box, it should save null/empty/nil in database.

```
<%= form_for(@user, local: true, html: {multipart: true}) do |form| %>


    <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
        <%= form.label :has_previously_used_hermes_cover, t('has_previously_used_hermes_cover') %>
        <p>

            <label>
                <%= check_box_tag "user[credit_report_available]", 1, @user.credit_report_available == 1 ? true : nil, id: "user_credit_report_available" %>

                <span class="btn <%= 'active' if (@user.credit_report_available) %>"> Yes </span>
            </label>

            <label>
                <%= check_box_tag "user[credit_report_available]", 0, @user.credit_report_available == 0 ? false : nil, id: "user_credit_report_available" %>

                <span class="btn <%= 'active' if (@user.credit_report_available == 0) %>"> No </span>
            </label>

        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m4">
        <%= form.submit class: 'btn', value: 'Send Application' %>
    </div>


<% end %>
```

```
def user_params
        params
            .require(:user)
            .permit(:credit_report_available)
end
```

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EN4Zjg4VJsdE3r6hYmvGiNV6yeLVy0ehKASDO1T3eb+er8TfdG+I0jRCQ/XuGGs8YEJLaUcfRkIV8pwR+N4JpNFg==", "user"=>{"credit_report_available"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send Application", "locale"=>"en"}
```

[image: Checkboxes]

Comment: so how are you sending that post/patch request, are you using AJAX?  Can you post your javascript code handling this event?

Comment: Its just a form in rails which is being sent via Post

Comment: Can you post the whole form please?  Do you also have an example of the params that get sent when submitting the form?

Comment: @RockwellRice I have added to code.

Comment: what about the params getting sent on submission?

Comment: @RockwellRice I have added the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you miss a colon?

`.permit(:credit_report_available)`

Comment: Sorry this was just an copy/paste error into stackoverflow for me.

Comment: Just copied your code and it works for me. Of course, checkboxes aren't synced, but parameter's value goes to the controller. Is there something else in your view/partial? Please show complete action log (new/create or edit/update).

Comment: The problem is that when I uncheck and check and then uncheck again the checkboxes, wrong value is saved in DB.